# Dynamically positioning scaled html image

Tags: html, css, positioning, scale, offset

There is a map placed as a background image on an html page. There is also a transparent image representing the sound waves originating from a certain point on the map, i.e the center of the waves. When the wave image is put on top of the map in its full size, the center of the wave image is on the correct position (pointing the desired center point on the map) with the `#waveImage {position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0}` css rule.

Problem is that I need to dynamically scale the wave image, never larger than its original size, based on an arbitrary algorithm. Obviously, when the image is smaller, the center point is offset from the original center, towards the right and bottom due to the initial css positioning, so I have to move the wave image so that the center of the wave still points to the same location on the map. What I need is the algorithm to calculate the correct offsets from right and bottom.

Some information that may be of further help: Wave image is 673px x 655px large, center of the wave is not on the center of the image.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. Or, at the very least, what you've got. Have you attempted anything to solve this problem? Can you show us a live (representative, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) demo of what you're working with at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar?

Comment: You can find an interactive demo of the problem [here](https://egemadra.net/demo1/). When you change the new width value the  wave image is rescaled. You can adjust the right and bottom offsets using the relevant input boxes. All I tried is to prepare this demo to find out about the formula. edit: I put a black dot on the map so that it can represent the static center, it's position does not have to be precise, it's there just to give an idea.

Comment: See CSS's `zoom`, `transform`, `transform-origin`, etc. features too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/k7uGu/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="map">
    <div class="signal-wrap">
        <img class="signal" src="signal.png">
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.map {
    background: url(map.png) no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    width:  770px;
    height: 688px;
}

.signal-wrap {
    position: absolute;

    /* find/set the center position on the map,
       using the right bottom corner for positioning
       to avoid "surprise" scrollbars appearing
    */
    right:  28%;
    bottom: 33%;

    /* change these to resize signal.
       you can always use a square shape (width=height),
       even if the image inside is not square
    */
    width:  10%;
    height: 10%;
}

.signal {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    /* image width will be equal to parent square's size
       height must not be set to keep original image shape
    */
    width: 100%;

    /* position of the center of the signal
       relative to the parent square
    */
    right:  -23%;
    bottom: -20%;
}
```

Comment: This is a very creative and inspiring work, thank you. What I don't get is how you found out about those magical numbers, namely the right: -23%; bottom: -20%; which seem to be doing the trick by keeping the center stable when the signal changes in size.

Comment: They mark the center of the wave, I just adjusted them until it looked good. Of course you can measure your original image and use `100*(wave_center_x - image_width)` or `100 - 100*(wave_center_x - image_width)`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks again. I was just wondering if there is any way without using such magic numbers. I mean a formula without using wave_center_x My initial attempt was to find the formula that automatically corrects the center by "nudging" from right and bottom but couldn't figure out.

Comment: Is it very pathetic if I can hardly understand my own answer?